# Condition for $L^p$ convergence of backwards martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Is there any condition that is known to be sufficient for $L^p, 1<p<\infty$ convergence of a backwards martingale (and why is it sufficient)?

I couldn't find anything else than the normal $L^1$ backwards martingale convergence theorem in textbooks.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $L^p$-boundedness is a sufficient condition (for both martingales and backward martingales).

Comment: @saz Thanks for your answer. $L^p$-boundedness in the sense that sup $E(|X_i^p|)<\infty$ or in a weaker way? Do you have any references?

Comment: Of course I mean sup $E(|X_i|^p)<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by $L^p$-boundedness. Unfortunately, I don't have a reference for this right now...

Comment: $E(|X_0|^p)<\infty$

Comment: @d.k.o.Do you have a reference or a proof? It seems to imply $L^p$ boundedness though.

Comment: It implies that $\sup|X_i|\in L^p$ (similarly to http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf page 215)